# выбор строк по условию

Tags: sql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такая таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно в зависимости от переменной osn выбирать строки сгруппированные по vidv и максимальной датой:

1. Если osn = 3030, то выбирать строки №12 и 13.
2. Если osn = 60090, то выбирать строки №12 и 13.
3. А если osn = 20370, то не выбирать ничего, так как есть строка с razdel='3030', vidv='1' и более поздней датой.

Вот такой код написал, дальше застрял:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT id, max(sroks), razdel, vidv
  FROM (
      SELECT id, sroks, srokpo, replace (razdel,' ', '') as razdel, vidv
      FROM vpl.manrazdel
  )
  GROUP BY id, razdel, vidv

)
where id='037016034158607001409576221452' and "Код" IN (@osn)
```

вот что он выдает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробую перевести на человеческий язык. Нужно выбрать актуальные razdel и vidv. Актуальность определяется по дате. Тоесть если есть несколько одинаковых vidv, но с разным значением razdel, то актуальный vidv будет с более поздней датой. Например vidv=1, razdel=20370, sroks=01.04.2016 и vidv=1, razdel=3030, sroks=01.04.2017, тут актуальным будет второй пример, так как дата у него более поздняя.
Эту половину задачи я решил приведенным кодом.

Но есть ещё одно условие. 
При значении переменной равной актуальному razdel, выбирать ВСЕ актуальные данные и скрывать не актуальные. 
Если osn = 3030, то выбирать строки №12 и 13.
Если osn = 60090, то выбирать строки №12 и 13.

При значении переменной равной НЕ актуальному razdel, не выбирать ничего.
Если osn = 20370, то не выбирать ничего, так как есть строка с актуальным razdel='3030', vidv='1' и более поздней датой, чем у razdel='20370', тоесть в данном случае razdel='20370' не актуален.

Comment: как то не понимаю логику выборки.

Comment: ничего не понял про osn и vidv.

Comment: Почему вы не указываете в вопросе какая у вас СУБД, возможности же у всех разные и подходы к решению проблемы то же ... Порывшись 10 минут в ваших предыдущих вопросах мне конечно удалось догадаться, что это DB2 ... Но всегда указывайте в в тексте вопроса какая СУБД используется. А теперь мне еще надо потратить минут 10 что бы перебить ваши данные с картинок для тестирования запроса ... _Всегда_ прикладывайте входные данные в виде текста !

Comment: То что вы хотите сначала получить строки для максимальных дат в пределах vidv я понял (делается через row_number()). Но вот почему вы хотите получить одинаковый результат и при osn=3030 и при 60090 я совершенно не понял.

Comment: Попробую перевести на человеческий язык. Нужно выбрать актуальные razdel и vidv. Актуальность определяется по дате. Тоесть если есть несколько одинаковых vidv, но с разным значением razdel, то актуальный vidv будет с более поздней датой. Например vidv=1, razdel=20370, sroks=01.04.2016 и vidv=1, razdel=3030, sroks=01.04.2017, тут актуальным будет второй пример, так как дата у него более поздняя.
Эту половину задачи я решил приведенным кодом.

Comment: Но есть ещё одно условие. 
При значении переменной равной актуальному razdel, выбирать ВСЕ актуальные данные и скрывать не актуальные. 
Если osn = 3030, то выбирать строки №12 и 13.
Если osn = 60090, то выбирать строки №12 и 13.

Comment: При значении переменной равной НЕ актуальному razdel, не выбирать ничего.
Если osn = 20370, то не выбирать ничего, так как есть строка с актуальным razdel='3030', vidv='1' и более поздней датой, чем у razdel='20370', тоесть в данном случае razdel='20370' не актуален.

Comment: Спасибо за критику, я учту. Просто я не программист совсем, пришлось заниматься не своим делом. База DB2 v9

Answer (score 1):

DB2 под руками нет, проверить не где. Надеюсь ваша версия поддерживает оконные функции ... Если по поддерживаемому синтаксису что то отличается, отлаживайте частями, начиная с внутреннего подзапроса.

```
select * from (
   select razdel, vidv, sroks, max(case when razdel=3030 then 1 end) over() test
     from (
      select razdel, vidv, sroks,
             row_number() over(partition by vidv order by sroks desc) RN
        from vpl.manrazdel
       where id='037016034158607001409576221452'
     ) as X where RN=1
  ) as Y where test=1
```

В внутреннем подзапросе нумеруем строки в порядке уменьшения дат, начиная нумерацию с 1 для каждого vidv. Берем только первые строки (с максимальной датой в группе). На следующем уровне запроса получаем максимум от формулы которая вернет 1 в случае если совпало условие на razdel. Так как этот максимум берется в оконной функции с пустым `over()` то мы получим 1 на всех записях выборки в случае совпадения условия хотя бы у одной строки. Остается на самом внешнем уровне запроса убедится, что 1 была установлена.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!